# Sorting MySQL results within a resultset

Tags: mysql

I have a resultset of lets say 10 results.
3 of them have a type 'Pears', and the next 3 have a type 'Apples' and the next three have a type of 'Bananas'. The last record has a type of 'Squeezing Equipment' - unrelated to the fruits.
How do I return this set of results (for pagination too) in a GROUPED order that I specify WITHOUT using any inherent sort factor like ALPHABETA or ID etc?
I have the all types at my disposal before running the code so they can be specified.
i.e.

```
ID | Bananas
ID | Bananas
ID | Bananas
ID | Apples
ID | Apples
ID | Apples
ID | Pears
ID | Pears
ID | Pears
ID | Squeezing Equipment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an order by clause. If you want "Squeezing Equipment" to come last use this:

```
ORDER BY CASE name
    WHEN 'Bananas' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Apples' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Pears' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Squeezing Equipment' THEN 4
    END
```

Comment: would this work: ORDER BY type = 'Bananas', name = 'Apples', name = 'Pears', name ? (or something similar)

Comment: @InnateDev: Yes that would work except it would give the results in the opposite order than you want. Or you could use a CASE - I've updated my answer.

Comment: a very versatile solution wouldnt you say?

Answer (score 0):

This will sort all of the types that are not `Squeezing Equipment` alphabetically first:

```
select ID, Type
from MyTable
order by case when Type = 'Squeezing Equipment' then 1 else 0 end, Type
```

If you have more than one non-fruit type, you can do:

```
select ID, Type
from MyTable
order by case when Type in ('Squeezing Equipment', 'some other type') then 1 else 0 end, Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a simple ORDER BY and GROUP BY achieve this? Or am I missing something?

```
SELECT ID, Type FROM TheFruityTable 
GROUP BY Type 
ORDER BY Type;
```

Comment: this would be ideal, its just that the last order by in your query will order by type alphabetically and I need to specify what comes first. i.e. Bananas must comes before Apples and then Pears.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Why not add another table which cross-references the types and specifies a sort order?